# ExpressJS - Optional part of the URL which is not a param?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route like this: `/products/123/versions/456`.

I want the sub resource to be optional, so I want one route path to handle both `/products/123` and `/products/123/versions/456`.

This doesn't work: `/products/:pid/versions?/:vid?`.

How do I make the `/versions/` part optional without making it a param with `:`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a named handler and use it for two routes:

```
function yourhandler(req, res) {
    // ...
}
app.get('/products/:pid', yourHandler);
app.get('/products/:pid/versions/:vid', yourHandler);
```

Or you can fight with regular expressions and optional parts. But those are really two different routes, not one, and it just happens that you want to use the same handler for both of them so using two `app.get()` (or whatever HTTP method it is) route definitions is the clearest way to solve it.

You can also add this if you need it as well:

```
app.get('/products/:pid/versions', yourHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks... I was trying to avoid two as I actually have `router.route('/products/:pid/:versions?/:vid?').all(handler).get(handler).put(handler).delete(handler)` which would be repeated twice (and just looks ugly)... But if that's the best way then so be it...

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/products/*',  (req, res, next){

const path = req.path;

//now use any logic on path as string

if(path.includes('versions')){

console.log('run version handler');

}else{
console.log('run else handler')}

}

//or const [product, version] = /\/products\/(.*)\/versions\/(.*)/.exec(path)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm sure that works, although it just feels a bit messy to grab a chuck of the url and work on it as a string.